# Generating User / Item interactions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I have a pandas dataframe (Interactions dataframe) with columns as User, Item, Rating.

```
Ratings ItemID   UserID
1      1172952     A74
1      1178735     176
4      341785     70C
3      136771     67E
2      1178883     383
```

Let's say I have two more dataframes with 200 users and 1000 ietms respectively. 
The problem is that in interactions dataframe, i need ratings for each user and each item combination. 0 rating for user/item combination if there is no interaction available for that user and item in interactions dataframe.

I have tried using a loop like this:

```
item_ids = np.repeat(item_data.id.values, len(user_data.id.values))
user_ids = np.tile(user_data.id.values, len(item_data.id.values))
ratings = np.empty([len(item_ids)])

for i in range(len(ratings)):
    inter = interactions.loc[(interactions['UserID'] == user_ids[i]) & (interactions["ItemID"] == item_ids[i]), "Ratings"]
    if not inter.empty:
        ratings[i] = inter.values[0]
    else:
        ratings[i] = 0

interactions = np.stack((ratings, item_ids, user_ids), axis=-1)
```

But it takes 40 seconds to complete for a ratings array of just 30,000 rows.
Is there a quick way of doing this?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation of the problem is a little sloppy, but I have a feeling that you need this:

```
interactions.set_index(['ItemID','UserID'])\
            .unstack().fillna(0).astype(int).stack()\
            .reset_index()
```

This code creates a rectangular table of users and items, fills the voids with zeros, and converts the table back into a "tall" vector. Output:

```
     ItemID UserID  Ratings
0    136771    176        0
1    136771    383        0
2    136771    67E        3
3    136771    70C        0
4    136771    A74        0
5    341785    176        0
6    341785    383        0
7    341785    67E        0
8    341785    70C        4
9    341785    A74        0
10  1172952    176        0
....
```

I assume that each item and each user (but not their combinations!) are referenced in the `interaction` table at least once. If not, some `merge`'ing with the other two tables is needed.

Comment: Thanks @DYZ for your help. It was extremely useful. It now runs under a second.

Comment: I will definitely work on my problem explanation skills though.